# Entity Framework : A predicateBuilder variable produce errors when declared as public

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework and `PredicateBuilder` from this library :https://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/a-universal-predicatebuilder/

I have 2 cases :

1. This works without problems :

   ```
   Private sub Mysub
      Dim pred1 = PredicateBuilder.True(Of MyObject)
      pred1 = pred1.And(Function(t2) t2.nr=5))
      ........ 
   End sub
   ```
2. This produces an error :

   ```
    Module Module1
      Public pred1 = PredicateBuilder.True(Of MyObject)
     ...
    End Module
    .....
    Private sub Mysub
      pred1=pred1.And(Function(t2) t2.nr=5))
       ........ 
    End sub
   ```

   The error is :

   > An unhandled exception of type 'System.MissingMemberException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
   >
   > Additional information: Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'And' accepts this number of arguments.

What's wrong ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Type inference only works for local variables (when Option Infer On is used).  In the second case, the best that VB can do is assume that the type of 'pred1' is 'Object' (this is legacy VB behavior when the type is omitted).

Comment: I doesn't used Option Infer ON , anyway  is there something I can do , because I need this variable to be global.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have Option Infer set at the project level?  Why don't you just include the type?

Comment: I don't have set this option , but it seems that this option is set on by default.

Comment: and what do you mean with "include the type". This is the way that predicatebuilder works.

Comment: "PredicateBuilder.True" must return some type - suppose it's "Foo" - then use "Public pred1 As Foo = PredicateBuilder.True(Of MyObject)".

Comment: For the project-level Option Infer setting, see the 'Compile' tab of the project properties.

Comment: But how can I know what type is ? The link that contain this library doesn't say nothing. Just explain how is used ? Can you detect something about the type from the library ?

Comment: There are a number of ways to determine the type - as you type the function name you should see it via intellisense, or you can check the first case where you use a local variable - the compiler will type 'pred1' appropriately - just hover over the variable name.

Comment: I try to make a declarations like this : Public pred1 As Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of MyObject) = PredicateBuilder.True(Of MyObject)() and I get this error : Value of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of System.Func(Of MyProg.MyObject, Boolean))' cannot be converted to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of MyProg.MyObject). So what may be the type ?

Comment: Maybe the type is 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of System.Func(Of MyProg.MyObject, Boolean)). actually I try to declare like this , and I'm not getting any error , but the problem is that in the second case that I have described , the variable inside the sub has an emty value and has no effect. ( Doesn;t produce any error but has no effect )